# react , how can i render multiple components in single route in react-router-dom v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

How can I render multiple components in single route in `react-router-dom` v6?

[This is how I render in react-router-dom v5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0fWG.png)

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/checkout">
            <Header />
            <Checkout />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Header />
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

How can I do same thing with `react-router-dom` v6?

Answer (score 1):

It's basically done the same way, but returning a ***single*** JSX node on the `Route` component's `element` prop.

Example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={(
            <>
              <Header />
              <Home />
            </>
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path="/checkout"
          element={(
            <>
              <Header />
              <Checkout />
            </>
          )}
        />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the case where you are wanting to render the `Header` with several routes then the recommended suggestion is to render what are called [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes) that render common logic and UI, *and* an `Outlet` component for nested routes to render their element into.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

export const Layout = () => (
  <>
    <Header />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);
```

...

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<Layout />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/checkout" element={<Checkout />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change Switch for Routes

```
const Home = () => (
  <> 
   <Header /> 
   <Checkout /> 
  </>
)
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

you can create a new component for reuse header in both elements